# LMDB variant offering finger B-Tree?

Tags: key-value-store, lmdb

A [finger B-Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finger_tree) is a B-Tree that tracks a user-specified associative "summarizing" operation on the leaves.  When nodes are merged, the operation is used to combine summaries; when nodes are split the summary is recalculated using the node's grandchildren (but no deeper nodes).

By updating the summary data with each split/merge, a finger B-Tree is able to answer queries a the summary over *any* arbitrary range of keys in at most O(log n) page lookups (i.e. along the path from the root down to the floorkey of the range and the ceilkey of the range).

I don't think LMDB supports this out of the box, but I'd be happy to be wrong.  Is anybody aware of an LMDB fork or variant which adds it?  If not, is there another lightweight persistent (not necessarily transactional) on-disk BTree library that does?

Comment: I used to work with CouchDB. finger B-Tree wasn't an option there, I think because it doesn't work with sharding.

Comment: @DavidKnipe I don't need a distributed database.

Answer (score 1):

RocksDB offers [custom compaction filters](https://github.com/facebook/rocksdb/wiki/Compaction) and [merge operators](https://github.com/facebook/rocksdb/wiki/Merge-Operator), which could be used to implement such summaries in a fairly efficient way, I think.  Of course, it's architecture is very different from LMDB.

Comment: Thanks for responding, but neither of these things allows O(log n) summaries.

Comment: Are you sure? The exact complexity class is a bit difficult to determine, but I think these operations are sub-linear, like other database updates.

Comment: Yes I am very sure, and the complexity class is very easy to define.  It also has nothing to do with what RocksDB calls compaction and merging.